# delay on the shot every 3 seconds in unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

sorry guys I'm new to c# and unity... what I want there is to execute spawner.SendMessage("shoot"); every 3 seconds.. it'll only execute once the condition is met.

```
    void Update(){

    //first we draw a line from our enemy to our player
    Debug.DrawLine (player.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);

    playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, myTransform.position);
    if (playerDistance < 40f) {

        lookAtPlayer ();

    }

    if(playerDistance <= 38f){
        if(playerDistance > 21){
            //move towards the player
            myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            spawner.SendMessage("shoot");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Harry, can you construct a sample code for me? if I use a for loop there and make a mod to execute the code via odd numbers. should I use the time.deltatime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get this straight, is this for an NPC type object? Are you building an Enemy AI?

If you just want him to shoot every 3 seconds while moving towards the target the following code should suffice:

```
float timer;

void Start()
{
    timer = 0;
}

void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (playerDistance <= 38 && playerDistance > 21)
    {
          myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
          if (timer > 3.0f)
          {
              spawner.SendMessage("shoot");
              timer = 0;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct sir @Haxxx.... I actually have the thought of using deltatime but don't know how to loop... I use for loop but didn't work.. your's works just fine.. thanks for the help.

Comment: Absolutely, people love to use other built in functions such as yield or invoke (probably not in your case) to manage Time variables but I find theirs nothing really quite like a simple float timer using Time.Deltatime. You have complete control over the outcome.

Comment: true... I've also tried yield but still can't do the 3 secs gap... so thanks again..

Comment: I don't know either sir @Haxxx.. the last time I saw your Answer I check and upvote it...